# Does there exist a infinite ring in which there are $3$ Frobenius homs?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Does there exist an infinite ring $R$ such that $(x + y)^b = x^b + y^b$, and similarly for $2$ other odd primes $a,c$?  Or what's the best that can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\mathbb Z/ 2 \mathbb Z$ we have

$$(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$$

for every prime $p$.

From here it follows immediately (I think) that an infinite product of copies of $\mathbb Z/ 2 \mathbb Z$ should do the trick.

**Added**
The ring is:

$$R=\{ (a_1,a_2,...,a_n,..) | a_n \in \mathbb Z/ 2 \mathbb Z \,;\, \forall n \in \mathbb N \}$$

With the addition and multiplication defined on each component:
$$(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}+(b_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}=(a_i+b_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}$$
$$(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}\cdot(b_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}=(a_i \cdot b_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}$$

Comment: Please explain more about the product of infinite copies, and what about modulo other primes?  Can $\Bbb{Z}$ be embedded in this infinite ring?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[X]$ does *not* have this property. $(1+X)^3 = 1 + X + X^2 + X^3 \neq 1 + X^3$.

Comment: How do you define multiplication in the “product of infinite copies” ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy That is a standard direct product of rings, addition and multiplication are defined component wise.

Comment: @N.S. So $\Bbb{Z}$ can't be embedded in this infinite copy of of $\Bbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: @nik ty, fixed that.

Comment: @EnjoysMath I don't think this idea works modulo any other number, the key is probably the fact that in $\mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z$ we have (nonzero)$+$nonzero$=0$... And this ring has the property that $x+x=0 \forall x$, which means $\mathbb Z$ cannot be embedded in it.

Comment: @EnjoysMath: If it could be, you would have $(x+y)^b=x^b+y^b$ in ${\bf Z}$, which you don't, unless $b=1$.

Comment: @EnjoysMath Note that for any prime $p$ there are infinitely many pairs of integer numbers $(x,y)$ such that $(x+y)^p \neq x^p+y^p$. If $\mathbb Z$ can be embedded into a ring $R$, then $R$ cannot have any Frobenius homs.